# Convert boost::container::boost basic_string to std::string

Tags: c++, boost, stdstring, boost-interprocess

Is there a simple way to do this?
I've tried the following:

```
typedef allocator<char,managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>
    CharAllocator;
typedef boost::container::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator>
    my_basic_string;

std::string s(my_basic_string);
```

Comment: What is `my_basic_string`? We can't answer this if you don't specify that. I can _assuming_ a `boost::container::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, boost::interprocess::allocator<boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> >` or similar, but if e.g. `char` doesn't match, there's gonna be much more conversion logic

Comment: @sehe : Updated to show what my_basic_string is...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @T.C. has said, you should use:

```
std::string s(my_basic_string.data(), my_basic_string.size());
```

or

```
std::string s(my_basic_string.begin(), my_basic_string.end());
```

I prefer the second, but both will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy element-wise (which any decent standard library implementation optimizes into `memcpy`):

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::interprocess;
typedef allocator<char, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> CharAllocator;
typedef boost::container::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator> my_shared_string;

std::string s(my_shared_string const& ss) {
    return std::string(ss.begin(), ss.end());
}
```

I called the string "my_shared_string" (because it's not any more "basic" than std::string). In fact it's good to notice this has everything to do with containers with custom allocators, and nothing with std::string or Boost Interprocess in particular:

```
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CharAllocator> my_shared_string;
```

behaves exactly the same for the given problem; So does e.g.:

```
typedef std::vector<char, CharAllocator> my_shared_vector;

std::vector<char> v(my_shared_vector const& ss) {
    return std::vector<char>(ss.begin(), ss.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed according to comments from @T.C.

You may use this:

```
std::string s(my_basic_string.c_str(), my_basic_string.size());
```

Comment: Assuming no embedded nulls. Otherwise the dual-iterator or the pointer-and-length constructor should be used.

Comment: Thanks T.C for your comments. But I don't understand your meaning, could you please provide a simple example?

Comment: If the string contained in `my_basic_string` has an embedded null character - `"abc\0def"`, for instance - then your code will initialize `s` to `"abc"` only since it stops at the first null character.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for example. But for a basic_string with "abc\0def", what's the meaning of "def"? When use the basic_string, i.e. my_basic_string.c_str(), my_basic_string.data(),  my_basic_string.size(), all ignore the def.  Please refer to my example: [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c87c414a84b1f0c1)

Comment: You are seeing the same issue here - if you use constructor taking a `const char *`, it's going to assume that the string terminates at the first null character it encounters. You need to [pass the length explicitly](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b856ac5602cd6c4).